# Undefined index: type_id - Catalog Search indexer

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch, indexer

Installed Smile-sa elasticSuite for Magento 2.3.3 and when indexing it gives this error:

```
Catalog Search indexer process unknown error:
Notice: Undefined index: type_id in /srv/html/src/vendor/smile/elasticsuite/src/module-elasticsuite-catalog/Model/Product/Indexer/Fulltext/Datasource/PriceData.php on line 64
```

Debugging that line 64 with a var_dump, i see that the dump looks like this:

```
    [18458]=>
  array(7) {
    [74]=>
    string(7) "1234566"
    [92]=>
    string(3) "N/A"
    [96]=>
    string(7) "Enabled"
    [122]=>
    string(13) "Taxable Goods"
    [71]=>
    string(4) "test"
    [72]=>
    string(4) "test"
    [73]=>
    string(4) "test"
  }
```

Now, this is happening on a dev site as a replica of the live site (same data) and with all extensions and themes REMOVED.

Trying the same on a fresh magento install i get this dump:

```
[1996]=>
  array(9) {
    ["entity_id"]=>
    string(4) "1996"
    ["attribute_set_id"]=>
    string(2) "10"
    ["type_id"]=>
    string(12) "configurable"
    ["sku"]=>
    string(5) "WSH06"
    ["has_options"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["required_options"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(19) "2020-04-16 11:36:46"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(19) "2020-04-16 11:36:46"
    ["visibility"]=>
    string(1) "4"
  }
```

Which is correct, and indeed smile-sa ElasticSuite looks for that type_id key, which is missing from the live server data dump.

What could cause this issue on live server?

Do you have any suggestions on what might be the solution here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved.

After installation, somehow the `catalog/search/engine` was set to `mysql` instead of `elasticsuite`.

Changing that to the right value solved the issue.